# A long delay (5-8 seconds) before ffmpeg receives first frame

Tags: ffmpeg

I transmit video file and receive it. I see a very long delay before first frame is received, around 5-8 seconds:

```
::sender.bat
ffmpeg -re -i sample.mp4 -vcodec h264 -tune fastdecode -tune zerolatency -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:1234

::receiver.bat
ffmpeg -i udp://127.0.0.1:1234 -y output.mp4
```

Answer (score 2):

It's due to the default x264 keyframe interval being long - 250 frames.

Keep it low. Add `-g 25` for a 25 frame interval.

Also, it helps to start the receiver before the sender.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer, there is a `-analyzeduration`  parameter which controls the amount of time needed to identify stream type. Default is 5 seconds , when I reduced it to 1 second (`-analyzeduration 1000000`), the movie started faster

Comment: Worth noting that `-analyzeduration` is an input option, so it must be applied before `-i`.